# How to make multiple buttons work independently using one function in java script?

Tags: javascript, html, button, show-hide

How to make more of this buttons so they will work independently? I know that it is all connected with id, but how to use one function, with multiple id's?

```js
function showme(id) {
  var divid = document.getElementById(id);
  var clicky = document.getElementById("clicky");
  if (divid.style.display == 'block') {
    divid.style.display = 'none';
    clicky.innerHTML = 'MORE <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>';
  } else {
    divid.style.display = 'block';
    clicky.innerHTML = 'LESS <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>';
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i>Click on more. I want to have two buttons, which work independently.</i><br>

<div class="tp-caption rev-btn rev-hiddenicon  rs-hover-ready rev-mre-btn" onclick="showme('widget');" href="javascript:;" id="clicky">MORE 
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
</div>

<div id="widget" style="display:none;">
  TEXT 1
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't try to cheat the requirement of putting code in the question by wrapping links to external sandboxes in a code block. Questions should be self contained. We shouldn't have to go off site just to review your initial issue. Now we can't see your code and that link isn't a link either

Comment: please, post a [mcve] here, in stackoverflow, not using a link to external sites. Use the `<>` button that exists in the toolbar when you [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would remove the `onclick` listener that you added inside HTML, that's not a good practice. I would add it on the JS, selecting all buttons/divs that I want to add a click listener, then attaching it.

To do that, you can select all of them by using `.getElementsByClassName()` (you can also use `querySelectorAll()`), with the elements saved in a variable, then loop all elements and attach the onclick function.

the function context ( `this`) would be the clicked button/div, knowing that, inside the function you can find the icon and the contained div (I moved the div inside because it makes more easier to find itand know which div should be toggled). After having the inner div and icon, now it's up to you to manage the open/close of the div and the icon transformation...

Take a look on the code below to see the main idea.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button-open-container");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
  buttons[i].onclick = showme;
}

function showme(ev) {   
  var spanText = this.querySelector(".my-text");
  var childDiv = this.querySelector(".my-container");  
  var icon = this.querySelector(".my-icon");  
  
  if (childDiv.style.display == "none"){
    childDiv.style.display = "block";
    icon.className = "my-icon fa fa-arrow-up";
    spanText.innerText = "LESS"
  }
  else{
    childDiv.style.display = "none";
    icon.className = "my-icon fa fa-arrow-down";
    spanText.innerText = "MORE";
  }    
}
```

```css
.button-open-container{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px;  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i>Click on more. I want to have two buttons, which work independently.</i><br>

<div class="tp-caption rev-btn rev-hiddenicon rs-hover-ready rev-mre-btn button-open-container">
  <span class='my-text'>MORE</span>
  <i class="my-icon fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
  <div class='my-container' style="display:none;">
    TEXT 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tp-caption rev-btn rev-hiddenicon rs-hover-ready rev-mre-btn button-open-container">
  <span class='my-text'>MORE</span>
  <i class="my-icon fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
  <div class='my-container' style="display:none;">
    TEXT 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does not work? Please, see that I did not add any logic to open and close the container, it's up to you, I'm not going to free code for you... I made all the logic until the part where the button is clicked and the icon and inner div is ready to be worked on

Comment: I am a beginner in js, so if I have known how to solve my question I would not ask

Comment: But you already had a logic to `display` and not display the div, your code show this... So I just answered your question *"How to make multiple buttons work independently..."* If you get my code, and inside the function you add your logic of open/close, then you'll be almost done...

Comment: I got to the point where they are independent. Thanks for that, but now I lost the feature of changing text and icon. Could you help me with this? https://codepen.io/micha-abaz/pen/xoegqo

Comment: ok dude, see my edited answer, I added a `span` to hold the text, that way I can find the span and change it's text... also a made the logic to open/close and also change the icon... Please,  if this is what you were looking for, mark as accepted answer. You were lucky that I had some free time here :)